# Custom button visibility

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button

Does any one knows how to add permission set on a custom button for the visibility, if the custom button is added on an aura component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a button on a layout be visible only to a specific group of users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34421/make-a-button-on-a-layout-be-visible-only-to-a-specific-group-of-users)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is out-of-the-box functionality for this. You could create a **custom permission** and assign that (through a permission set) to the users who should have access to the button. Then, create a controller method that checks if the user has access to the custom permission and shows the button based on that.

Checking if a user has a custom permission is extremely easy in Apex -

`FeatureManagement.checkPermission('<custom_permission_api_name>');`

Use the above code in your controller class.

Comment: Thanks, it works.